# Fancytree LazyLoad folder checkbox with multi-hier not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

**Setup**

I am loading a directory tree via [lazyload](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#lazy-loading) and have the checkboxes with multi-hier activated.

Selection and deselection works fine, when i select a subfolder the parentfolder is automatically 'semi-selected', when i select/deselect a parent all the children get selected/deselected.

**Problem**

But once i reach a folder that has no further subfolders and i try to expand this folder (which then removes the + icon) and then select this folder, i can't deselect it anymore. At least not correctly. Upon deselection it becomes semi-selected (only visually, it is not marked as selected when polling the tree).

When i now select its parent, this child becomes selected, but when i deselect the parent the child stays selected.

Can anybody tell me whats going on here?
Did i implement it wrong, or is this a bug?

**Example**

[LINK](http://spielwiese.ermert.es/public/fancytree/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a known bug: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/250
Fixed in the current development code and the upcoming release

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it, the dev version fixed it. As i am new to Fancytree i wasn't sure if it was a bug or me, fixed in the latest dev version you can download in Git.